# Support for active STM library

Tags: java, stm

I am looking for a java STM library which is under active development, so that we can start using that in our product. I have looked at multiverse, and objectfabric from wikipage, but looks like there is no development going on for them.

I wanted to check scalaSTM library. I see its latest release a year back. So wanted to check if it is still under active development?

Comment: The problem with STM is it is often slower and more complicated than single threaded code.  What do you want to use STM for?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [Disuptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/).

Take a look at the articles and presentations listed on that page.  Maybe Disruptor is a good fit.  I know that when I think about STM, this is what comes to mind.

Here is one quote from Martin Fowler's blog post about LMAX and their Disruptor library.

> Given the shift to multi-core thinking, this kind of demanding performance would naturally suggest an explicitly concurrent programming model - and indeed this was their starting point. But the thing that got people's attention at QCon was that this wasn't where they ended up. In fact they ended up by doing all the business logic for their platform: all trades, from all customers, in all markets - on a single thread. A thread that will process 6 million orders per second using commodity hardware.